# Powershell - Match one or another

Tags: powershell

I have a log file that has user login/logout events, formatted like this:

> 11/29/19 10:46:41.976 S I [T-22156] - User Logout: Bob Jones (Home)
>
> 11/29/19 10:46:51.293 S I [T-22156] - HTTP UserMgr: Start User login notify for user:  Jane Smith (Studio)

I am calling the above text from my log file using Get-Content and saving it to $testtext.

In Expresso, I built the following regex, and when I run it, Expresso matches my DateTime, Status, and Name without any errors on the above text.

```
$regex = [regex]::new('(?<DateTime>\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})(?:.*)(?<Status>User\slog\w{2,3})(?:.*?)(?<Name>[A-Z][a-zA-Z]+\s[A-Z][a-zA-Z]+\s\([A-Z]+\))')
```

But when I run the following in Powershell, it only outputs the Login events

```
    $parsed = foreach ($text in $testtext) {
    $match = $regex.Match($text)
   [PSCustomObject][ordered]@{
    Date  = $match.Groups["DateTime"].Value
    Status =  $match.Groups["Status"].Value
    Name = $match.Groups["Name"].Value
    }
}

$parsed | Out-GridView
```

How can I have my regex look at each line and fine both matches?

Comment: instead of one massive regex, have you tried doing it in steps? 1st match for `logout:|login:`. 2nd parse those lines for the other info.

Comment: I have, but I need the DateTime, Status, and Name to output together on the same line.  If i split them into 3, then output them, it outputs all my DateTime, then all Status, then all Name.

Comment: i did not say to break anything. [*grin*] your text should be in lines already ... so find the ones the match `Login:|Logout:`, then parse each such line for the info that you want.

Answer (score 0):

the following is what i meant by "two steps instead of one massive regex". [*grin*]

what it does ...

- fakes reading in text file
  replace that entire section with a `Get-Content` call to load your text file as an array of lines of text.
- iterates thru the resulting collection of lines
- tests for either `login` or `logout`
- applies a different regex for each type of line
  making a regex for both lines is both more complex and somewhat beyond my skill level. [*grin*]
- creates a PSCO for each set of matches
- sends the PSCO out to the $Results collection
- displays that collection

at that point, you can export to CSV fairly simply.

the code ...

```
# fake reading in a plain text file
#    in real life, use Get-Content
$InStuff = @'
11/29/19 10:46:41.976 S I [T-22156] - User Logout: Bob Jones (Home)
11/29/19 10:46:51.293 S I [T-22156] - HTTP UserMgr: Start User login notify for user: Jane Smith (Studio)
'@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine

$Results = foreach ($IS_Item in $InStuff)
    {
    if ($IS_Item -match 'login')
        {
        $Null = $IS_Item -match '^(.*\s.*) S I .* user (.*) notify for user: (.*)$'
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            TimeStamp = $Matches[1]
            Type = $Matches[2]
            User = $Matches[3]
            }
        }
    if ($IS_Item -match 'logout')
        {
        $Null = $IS_Item -match '^(.*\s.*) S .* User (.*): (.*)$'
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            TimeStamp = $Matches[1]
            Type = $Matches[2]
            User = $Matches[3]
            }
        }
    }

$Results
```

output ...

```
TimeStamp             Type   User               
---------             ----   ----               
11/29/19 10:46:41.976 Logout Bob Jones (Home)   
11/29/19 10:46:51.293 login  Jane Smith (Studio)
```

Answer (score -1):

I maybe understanding it wrong. But it looks like the contents are only 1 object.  Then when you do a foreach it only checks the one object.

What I would check...
What is the value of $testtext.count?  You want it to match the number of lines, not be 1.

If it is 1, then you need to look at splitting each line to be treated as an object.

Comment: My $testtext.count is 69.  There are multiple lines in my log file, but each line has either a Login event or Logout event.  I am looking to capture each line with just the data that I need, excluding all the other characters.  In Expresso, it runs flawlessly for each login/logout event, but Powershell only catches the Login events.

Comment: PLEASE do not post replies or comments as _ANSWERS_. if you haven't enuf reputation to reply, you can get such by reading thru the rules. i think that gives you 100 reputation points.